# R - Error in setwd(tempdir()) : cannot change working directory

Tags: r

I am having serious problems related with setwd. Just starting R session the first message I get (doing nothing) is:

> Error in setwd(dir) : cannot change working directory

Then I had problems using specific libraries. For example with `plotly`, I can download the library but when I try to apply the funcion `plot_ly` I get the same error.

Now I am trying to use R Markdown so I need to install `tinytex`, when I execute `tinytex::install_tinytex()` I get this error:

> Error in setwd(tempdir()) : cannot change working directory

I have been looking information about this issue but with not success. How can I solve this?

Comment: Check to see if the path you have in `setwd()` actually exists on your pc

Comment: Do you have anything in Rprofile.site or similar files? What is the output of `tempdir()`? Do you have user rights in that directory?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Try to delete the .rstudio directory in your home directory.

Comment: @Roland's questions are crucial.  You may have an environment variable specifying a temp dir that doesn't exist.  R looks for TMPDIR, TMP and TEMP .  If none exist, the defaults vary between Unix and Windows:  on Unix, the default is /tmp.   On Windows, it will use the R_USER directory.

Comment: How can I check if I have something in Rprofile.site or if I have user rights?

Comment: This is what I get when I execute tempdir() "C:\\Users\\usuario\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp8KsyiN"

Comment: In Rprofile.site I have this:
# options(papersize="a4")
# options(editor="notepad")
# options(pager="internal")

# set the default help type
# options(help_type="text")
  options(help_type="html")

# set a site library
# .Library.site <- file.path(chartr("\\", "/", R.home()), "site-library")

# set a CRAN mirror
# local({r <- getOption("repos")
#       r["CRAN"] <- "http://my.local.cran"
#       options(repos=r)})

# Give a fortune cookie, but only to interactive sessions
# (This would need the fortunes package to be installed.)
#  if (interactive()) 
#  fortunes::fortune()

Comment: I have a student with the same problem, also installing tinytex, if you found out why please tell us something!

Comment: At the end we found that the previous user of that computer made a lot of changes in the software so we decided to create a new windows user and I stopped having that problem.